# Substitute \mathbb fonts in Minion Pro with Blackboard Bold from Lucida Bright fonts

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, minionpro, blackboard

I would like to substitute Blackboard Bold fonts from Lucia Bright (that I have installed on my systems) in documents using Minion Pro. If I simply use Minion Pro style, I get the \mathbb fonts from CM set, I think Lucida Bright \mathbb fonts better match MinionPro. My current set up looks like this:

```
\usepackage[mathlf,textlf,minionint]{MinionPro}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{Myriad-LF}
```

I think (but not sure) that I need to add a line like

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{xxx}{lbmad}{m}{n}
```

But I am not sure what xxx should be. Any ideas what the correct way to do this is? I am using pdflatex to compile my latex files on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have `MinionPro`, but this should work.

```
\documentclass{article}

% hacked from lucimatx.sty
\DeclareFontEncoding{LMR}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LMR}{hlcm}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontFamily{LMR}{hlcm}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMR}{hlcm}{m}{n}{<->hlcra}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMR}{hlcm}{b}{n}{<->hlcda}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{LMR}{hlcm}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{bold}{LMR}{hlcm}{b}{n}

\begin{document}
$\mathbb{A}\mathbb{B}$

\boldmath$\mathbb{A}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a version with also `\mathcal`:

```
\documentclass{article}

% hacked from lucimatx.sty
\DeclareFontEncoding{LMR}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LMR}{hlcm}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontFamily{LMR}{hlcm}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMR}{hlcm}{m}{n}{<->hlcra}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMR}{hlcm}{b}{n}{<->hlcda}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{LMR}{hlcm}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{bold}{LMR}{hlcm}{b}{n}

\DeclareFontFamily{OMS}{hlcy}{\skewchar\font=48}
\DeclareFontShape{OMS}{hlcy}{m}{n}{<->hlcry}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMS}{hlcy}{b}{n}{<->hlcdy}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{hlcy}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{bold}{OMS}{hlcy}{b}{n}

\begin{document}
$\mathbb{A}\mathbb{B}\mathcal{C}\mathcal{D}$

\boldmath$\mathbb{A}\mathcal{B}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you also give commands necessary to substitute \mathcal with the Lucida bright fonts? similar to what  you did for \mathbb.

Comment: @per Done; once the mechanic is known it's easy.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please shed some light on the mechanism? You apparently see something in lucimatx.sty that I am not able to see!!

Comment: It's just defining the font families and shapes; `lucimatx` uses a wrapper for defining the shapes. But you dont find `\DeclareMathAlphabet` because the fonts are shared with symbol fonts, so there's `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet` for `\mathbb` and `\mathcal`.