# How to get the Blackboard Bold from Bookman font in the report class?

Tags: fonts

How to get the Blackboard Bold from `Bookman` font in the `report` class? Is there any code for this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As far as I know, there's no blackboard bold Bookman font.

Comment: Are you using Bookman as your main text font? If so, what accompanying math font did you choose?

Comment: I use amsfonts.

Comment: Then just use `amsfonts` with the `report` class without Bookman and you will get the same blackboard bold since `amsfonts` is responsible for defining it in that case. If this doesn't answer your question, please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating the issue so that we can see what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to demonstrate, here are the results of using `amsfonts` with Bookman:

[image: Bookman with amsfonts]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand*{\alphatest}{A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z}

\begin{document}

\[
  \mathbb{\alphatest}
\]

\end{document}
```

Here are the results of using `amsfonts` alone (the fact that it is `report` rather than `article` makes no difference to the fonts used):

[image: amsfonts alone]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand*{\alphatest}{A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z}

\begin{document}

\[
  \mathbb{\alphatest}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you suggest for these bold face?

Comment: @Suresh To the best of my knowledge, there is no bold version of the AMS blackboard fonts. The font definition file only includes a medium series. I'm now confused about what you are asking since your original question was about using a font used in one context in a different context. But now you seem to be saying that you want to use some other font and I'm not clear what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: Kindly go through the following link, the code is given for LMR font. Similarly, is it possible for amsfonts? If so pls send the code.                                                               http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145642/substitute-mathbb-fonts-in-minion-pro-with-blackboard-bold-from-lucida-bright-f

Comment: If possible for bookman font also

Comment: @Suresh The answer to the first question is: no, it is not possible for the AMS blackboard bold because there is no bold version of that font. It is only available in medium weight. The code I've given enables the AMS blackboard bold in medium weight and that is all the AMS fonts support. If you want bold series blackboard bold, you need to use a font which provides bold. You could use the code given in that link if you wished to but it will only work if you have the Lucida Bright fonts installed. (You have to purchase them from TUG.)

Comment: @Suresh The second question doesn't make any sense. There is no blackboard bold in Bookman. So whatever setup you use for blackboard bold is entirely independent of Bookman. You can use the code I've given to enable the AMS blackboard bold. Or you can use the code you linked to, if you have Lucida Bright. Or you can use any other blackboard bold configuration. It is just irrelevant whether you are using Bookman or not because Bookman does not touch the definitions of `\mathbb` etc.